# Setup a Blacklist Service for blocking IPs with SMTP Service Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, blacklist

Can the SMTP Service on Windows 2003 Server be setup to work with one or more IP blacklist providers? If not, what about Windows 2003 Server in general?

Answer (score 1):

IIS's internal SMTP component can't do such fancy things; that's the only mail engine in Windows Server 2003, and it's not up to this job.

I'm afraid you'll have to get a mail server in order to do this kind of filtering; if you want to stick with a Microsoft solution, Exchange 2007 can use blacklist providers.

Comment: What about blocking with Windows 2003 in general? Maybe a program that blocks IPs using IPSec rules, feed by blacklist provider?

Comment: Windows doesn't have anything of this on its own, you need a third-party solution.